# Dependency-Inversion-Principal: Should I use an extra Project/DLL for interfaces?

Tags: c#, architecture, layer

If I have a Layered-Architecture like:
Business-Layer -> Data Access Layer, how can I implement the Dependency-Inversion-Principal properly?

As the principal states the interface used by the lower level (DAL) should be defined by the higher level. But if I define the interface within the business layer DLL I'll get a circular dependency. Is it a good idea to move the interface into a seperate DLL that is used by both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion - yes. Then projects in a solution will be like (but it's only an example, I don't know your specific situation):

- DependencyInjectionProject.InjectInterfaces (references to all projects) - this project include logic to resolve interface dependencies
- Domain.YourBusinessLogic (reference to interfaces)
- Infrastructure.Interfaces
- Infrastructure.Implementations (reference to interfaces)

Finally, in your end/client application you can reference to DependencyInjectionProject.InjectInterfaces which resolve dependencies within business logic.

Comment: Keep in mind that Infrastructure.Interfaces also needs to define the objects to be exchanged as well - unless they are in a 4th assembly that all the assemblies reference.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there's no downside keeping your abstractions separate. They can be implemented/extended multiple ways in multiple different projects. You will only be referencing the abstractions projects where the dependencies is needed. Without necessarily knowing about implementations.
This approach has way more upsides, than a few minor downsides like increase of projects number.

Comment: Also this way it will be much easier to maintain solution and code base. And if in future you will decide to refactor your code base and use a different architecture, it will benefit you there as well.

Answer (score 0):

@ElConrado's not wrong, but it is a bit open to opinion.  Yes, you can use separate assemblies but you don't have to; DI is not just a assembly / package level thing - but granted that's where a lot of value is since it's how you can swap parts of the system by re-deploying isolated DLL's without having to re-deploy (or compile) the whole thing.

Typically I have a `Common` assembly / namespace, and have my DTO's and Interfaces in there, because most of the time that works well for the size and complexity of the app I am dealing with.  You could put the abstraction interfaces in a separate assembly, but I don't see what practical value that would give you.

In terms how you could do it in C#:

**Assembly: MyApp.Common, Namespace: MyApp.Common.Utilities**

```
// Utility that instantiates concrete providers 
// (classes that implement the abstractions / interfaces) 
// like IContentDataProvider.
public class ProviderLoader
{
  public static object CreateInstance(string fullTypeNameConfigKey)
  {
     ...
  }

  public static object CreateInstance(string fullTypeName)
  {
     ...
  }
}
```

**Assembly: MyApp.Common, Namespace: MyApp.Common.Interfaces.IDataProvider**

```
// Defines abstract data access methods
public interface IContentDataProvider
{
  ContentInfo Content_SELECT_ByContentID(int contentId);
}
```

**Assembly: MyApp.Common, Namespace: MyApp.Common.Info**

```
// Dumb DTO's / POCO's, used by the interfaces / abstractions 
// as a way of exchanging data between layers, whilst still 
// maintaining a clean separation.
public class ContentInfo
{
  ...
}
```

**Assembly: MyApp.SQLDataProvider, Namespace: MyApp.SQLDataProvider**

*References MyApp.Common*

```
// Concrete data provider
public class ContentDataProvider : IContentDataProvider
{
  public ContentInfo Content_SELECT_ByContentID(int contentId)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

And now the fun part, bringing it all together:

**Assembly: MyApp.Business, Namespace: MyApp.Business**

*References MyApp.Common*

```
// Concrete data provider
public class ContentPublisher
{
    // Not strictly necessary, but Lazy-Load is one 
    // way to instantiate the provider where you need it.
    private static MyApp.Common.Interfaces.IDataProvider.IContentDataProvider _iContentDataProvider;
    private static MyApp.Common.Interfaces.IDataProvider.IContentDataProvider IContentDataProvider
    {
        get
        {
            if (_iContentDataProvider== null)
            {
                // Here the type of concrete provider would 
                // be loaded based on a value set in a config file 
                // so the parameter here would be a config-key.
                // But you could use other approaches. 
                _iContentDataProvider= MyApp.Common.Utilities.ProviderLoader.CreateInstance(...) as MyApp.Common.Interfaces.IDataProvider.IContentDataProvider;
            }
            return _iContentDataProvider;
        }
    }

    // Use the IContentDataProvider to access the concrete implementation:
    public static ContentItem GetContentItemById(int contentId)
    {
        ContentInfo contentInfo = IContentDataProvider.Content_SELECT_ByContentID(contentId);
        ...
        // Take the lowly ContentInfo DTO and use it, 
        // sprinkled with some other Business Layer magic, 
        // to return ContentItem.
    }
}
```

Whilst it might seem a little overkill, there's no reason why you couldn't take the same approach (use of interfaces, provider loader, etc) and put it all in one assembly, and let your app's users leverage it - e.g. to choose which algorithm gets used for some purpose. They could do that via config setting, or even just by changing the app's state in-memory though the UI.